# pd.read_csv just not responding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to load all the csv files of directory in list of dataframes in python. These are about 1000 files and 300kb each.

I was able to read 5000 files of exactly same structure previously from another directory using this small code.
However, now I am facing a weird problem. When I run this, each time the script gets stuck at pd.read_csv(). For example, it reads 623 files and get stuck at x624.csv --- next time when I run it, it gets stuck at x599.csv

When I say "it get stuck" I mean pd.read_csv() will not give me an error, not a warning and also no answer.

I tried to debug as well and verifed the csv files as well. They all are okay.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ipdb as ipdb
import os, glob

dfList = []
address = r"C:/Users/ja.mas/Documents/ADiv/myDir"

for file in os.listdir(address):
    print(file)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(address + "/" + file)
        dfList.append(df)
    except:
        print("file skipped")
```

Comment: Could it be running out of memory? If you open Task Manager, does it report that all memory is being used?

Comment: @NickODell -> It is not a memory issue because the directly has very little data compared to the other directory where my code ran successfully. Those were also similar files.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would ensure that all data you are loading into a dataframe is needed (for example, can you only read in specific columns you need). If that isn't a solution, I would use the chunksize parameter and concatenate the results. Here is an example from Panda's docs [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html?highlight=textfilereader#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk):

```
In [216]: with pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", sep="|", chunksize=4) as reader:
   .....:     reader
   .....:     for chunk in reader:
   .....:         print(chunk)
   .....: 
   Unnamed: 0         0         1         2         3
0           0 -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
1           1 -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061
2           2  0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412  2.565646
3           3  1.431256  1.340309 -1.170299 -0.226169
   Unnamed: 0         0         1         2         3
4           4  0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317
5           5 -0.076467 -1.187678  1.130127 -1.436737
6           6 -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605
7           7  0.875906 -2.211372  0.974466 -2.006747
   Unnamed: 0         0         1         2         3
8           8 -0.410001 -0.078638  0.545952 -1.219217
9           9 -1.226825  0.769804 -1.281247 -0.727707
```

However, Pandas notes that:

> Chunking works well when the operation you’re performing requires zero or minimal coordination between chunks. For more complicated workflows, you’re better off using another library. ([2](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html?highlight=chunksize#use-chunking))